# How to invert / reflect a 3DS Max Scene

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, maxscript

I want to invert/reflect a scene (collection of meshes).

Example (in 3d space):
Before:
[1][2]
After:
[2][1]

Like if you would reflect it.
I hope you understand what i mean.
How should i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to mimic with MaxScript what the Mirror tool does, it does like this, for example mirroring X axis:

```
for i=1 to objects.count do
(
  scale objects[i] [-1,1,1]
  objects[i].pos.x = -objects[i].pos.x
)
```

You should be warned that after that your objects scale will be negative, and that could be problematic in some situations.